# Knockout binding for onsenui tabbar

Tags: knockout.js, onsen-ui

I'm using onsen UI with knockoutJS.
Page navigation and binding of viewmodels is done like this codepen (http://codepen.io/frankox/pen/RrrXbV):

```
window.OnsNavigatorElement.rewritables.link = function(element, target, oons, callback) {
    ko.applyBindings(options.viewModel, target);
    callback(target);
};

function gotoFoobar(){
    document.querySelector('ons-navigator').pushPage('foobar.html', {viewModel: new FoobarViewModel()});
}

function FoobarViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    this.variableInFoobarViewmodel = "foobar";
}
```

My view in foobar.html:

```
  <ons-page>  
    <ons-tabbar>
        <ons-tab page="data.html"><span data-bind="text: variableInFoobarViewmodel"></span></ons-tab>
    </ons-tabbar>

    <ons-template id="data.html">
        <ons-page>
            Variable: <span data-bind="text: variableInFoobarViewmodel"></span>
        </ons-page>
    </ons-template>
</ons-page>
```

Result: variableInFoobarViewmodel in the tab-title resolves correctly, but inside the tabbar page data.html it resolves empty.

I would expect it to resolve properly, since the template data.html is inside foobar.html.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<ons-template id="data.html">` is just a template, it's not part of the page so it won't have any view model. The Codepen that you link to is only prepared to be used with `ons-navigator` and was actually for beta.5. We already have the released version +2.0.0 so it's better to update. I made another quick example with better integration for all the components: [tutorial app](https://tutorial.onsen.io/embed-compact.html?external=https://tutorial.onsen.io/tutorial/other/knockout_bindings.html&docs=false) - [codepen](https://codepen.io/frankdiox/pen/XjYVRz?editors=101)

The navigator uses the same strategy with `navi.pushPage(page, {data: {viewModel: ...}})`. The rest of the pages are linked to a viewModel by the ID but you can change that easily.

Comment: Thank you! The example for beta5 was the only example of knockout+onsen that I could find that time.